# Bound ListView won't accept List<VisualStateGroup> as ItemsSource in WinUI 3. Any idea why?

Tags: listview, collections, binding, dependency-properties, winui-3

I am using version 1.1.5 of the Windows App SDK to create a Desktop application in WinUI 3. I've created a `Page` on which I have a `ListView` that I'd like to have display information from a `List` of `VisualStateGroup` items. For some reason, I get a "Value does not fall within the expected range." error whenever the `ListView` loads the list.

Here's the `Page`:

```xaml
<Page {some stuff}>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate" x:DataType="VisualStateGroup">
            <TextBlock x:Name="groupName"  Text="{x:Bind Name}" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <ListView x:Name="LayoutRootVisualStateGroupListListView"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"
            Width="Auto"
            Height="Auto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code-behind includes the following in the class definition:

```c#
public ObservableCollection<VisualStateGroup> LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList { get; set; }

public FooPage()
{
    // ...
    LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList = new(VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(ShellPage.ViewModel.UILayoutRoot));
}
```

Parsing `LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList` appears to throw the error but I don't know why.

Converting the `LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList` to a `List<string>` (in code) and passing it into the `ListView` works. Using code to add strings to to the `Items` collection works:

```c#
foreach (var group in LayoutRootVisualStateGroupList) LayoutRootVisualStateGroupListListView.Items.Add(group.Name);
```

Might this have something to do with proper change notification? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with VisualStates in the ViewModel. Do you have any source or sample that you are using for reference?

Comment: Although I don't think it has anything to do with the problem, I'm trying to trace VisualState changes in the WindowChrome. I don't think anything in the example is in the ViewModel, except the UILayoutRoot property which is the root of the visual tree in the WindowChrome. As I was writing the trace code, I thought I'd watch the state changes in a ListView but the ListView (or perhaps the ObservableCollection) isn't working as I expected.