# How to write a DataTemplate that works with a VisualStateGroup in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, data-binding, templating, winui-3

I've been trying to pass collections of `VisualStateGroup` objects to various `ContentControl`s in WinUI 3 (1.1.5) but I keep getting a *'Value does not fall within the expected range.'* error. I think I've defined an appropriate `DataTemplate`, but nothing seems to work. Here's a simple example `Page` from a new `Template Studio` Winui 3 project:

```c#
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    public ShellPage ShellPage { get; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();

        ShellPage = App.GetService<ShellPage>();
        var rootGrid = (ShellPage.IsLoaded) ? VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ShellPage.NavigationViewControl, 0) as Grid : null;
        if (rootGrid != null)
        {
            var listOfVisualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(rootGrid);
            if (listOfVisualStateGroups?.Count > 0) cControl.Content = listOfVisualStateGroups[0];
        }
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Page
    x:Class="TestCollection.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <ContentControl x:Name="cControl">
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="VisualStateGroup">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

All this does is fetch the list of `VisualStateGroups` attached to the `NavigationViewControl` of a vanilla WinUI 3 project. The first group in the list is then displayed in the `ContentControl cControl` by assigning it to `Content`. But the assignment causes the error.

I gather there is something wrong with the `DataTemplate`, but I can't figure out what. A similar problem occurs if I try to create a templated `ListViewItem` with a `VisualStateGroup` object.

This is a significant refinement of a question I asked a few days ago (please see: [Bound ListView won't accept List<VisualStateGroup> as ItemsSource in WinUI 3. Any idea why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73839546/14062288), if curious). My purpose in asking is to better understand the mechanics and requirements of templating. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update: 10/2/2022**

I haven't found an explanation for the error but I have found that simply wrapping the `VisualStateGroup` and `VisualState` classes lets me use collections of the new classes as I would expect. `Thing1` and `Thing2` are just copies of `VisualStateGroup` and `VisualState` (both of which are sealed and can't be inherited directly).

```c#
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; }
    public ShellPage ShellPage { get; }

    public List<Thing1> Things { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Thing2> OtherThings { get; set; } = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();

        ShellPage = App.GetService<ShellPage>();
        var rootGrid = (ShellPage.IsLoaded) ? VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ShellPage.NavigationViewControl, 0) as Grid : null;
        if (rootGrid != null)
        {
            var listOfVisualStateGroups = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(rootGrid);
            foreach (var group in listOfVisualStateGroups) Things.Add(new(group));
            if (listOfVisualStateGroups?.Count > 0)
                foreach (var state in listOfVisualStateGroups[0].States) OtherThings.Add(new(state));
        }
    }
}

// copy of VisualStateGroup
public partial class Thing1
{
    public VisualState CurrentState { get; }
    public CoreDispatcher Dispatcher { get; }
    public DispatcherQueue DispatcherQueue { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public IList<VisualState> States { get; }
    public IList<VisualTransition> Transitions { get; }

    public Thing1(VisualStateGroup group)
    {
        CurrentState = group.CurrentState;
        Dispatcher = group.Dispatcher;
        DispatcherQueue = group.DispatcherQueue;
        Name = group.Name;
        States = group.States;
        Transitions = group.Transitions;
    }
}

// copy of VisualState
public partial class Thing2
{
    public CoreDispatcher Dispatcher { get; }
    public DispatcherQueue DispatcherQueue { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public SetterBaseCollection Setters { get; }
    public IList<StateTriggerBase> StateTriggers { get; }
    public Storyboard Storyboard { get; set; }

    public Thing2(VisualState state)
    {
        Dispatcher = state.Dispatcher;
        DispatcherQueue = state.DispatcherQueue;
        Name = state.Name;
        Setters = state.Setters;
        StateTriggers = state.StateTriggers;
        Storyboard = state.Storyboard;
    }
}
```

```xaml
<Page
    x:Class="TestCollection.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:views="using:TestCollection.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListView Margin="0,0,20,20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Header="Things (VisualStateGroups)"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Things}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="views:Thing1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ListView Margin="0,0,20,20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Header="OtherThings (VisualStates)"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind OtherThings}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="views:Thing2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Any idea why an `ObservableCollection<Thing1>` works but an `ObservableCollection<VisualStateGroup>` doesn't?

Comment: Collections of VisualState objects cause the same behavior in ListView/GridView.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference between `VisualStateGroup`/`VisualState` and `Thing1`/`Thing2` is that `VisualStateGroup`/`VisualState` inherit from [`DependencyObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).
It could be that for this reason, you would have to use [`DependencyObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.dependencyobjectcollection?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) instead of `List`.

If you want to rule out `DataTemplate` being the problem, remove the `x:DataType` and use static text in the `TextBlock` (instead of using a binding). That could help isolate the problem.